# limit flex height based on parent grid area - when flex-direction

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to do a flex-wrap with flex-direction column (see #design-content) placed in a grid area (see design-form).
#design-content needs to have the height of the grid area it is placed in.
This works as long as #design-form does NOT have `flex-direction: column;` but as soon as I add that line the element + the parent grid-template-row height changes (as shown in computed tab in chrome)

Is there a way to force #design content to respect height from the parent elements?

CSS

```css
main {
    height: 80vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
      "ref"
      "design";
    grid-template-rows: fit-content(100%) 1fr;
}

#design-form {
  grid-area: design;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr min-content;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "form    "
    "controls";
  gap: var(--standard-gap);
}

#design-content {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-style: dotted dashed solid double;
  gap: var(--standard-gap); 
}
```

Relevant html

```html
<main>
<form id="design-form" class="active">         
   <div id="design-content">
            <div class="card">
                <h4>setup</h4>
                <div class="check-field-element"> 
                <input 
                   type="checkbox" 
                   name="checkbox" 
                   id="trophicMethod"}="">
                <label>trophic method</label>
            </div>
            ... more cards
   </div>
</form>
</main>
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML structure ?

Comment: @CharlesLavalard, yes. I have added the structure that matter to this problem